# foriegn key references not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a reference in mysql using primary and foriegn key reference but it is not showing
[db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwK6O.png)
this is the schema of my database

```
[CREATE TABLE fname(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR(29))

CREATE TABLE parent(
p_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id INT,
FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES fname(id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read in a comment to a remove answer, you want to insert a value in *parent* and have it automatically available in *fname*. This is not the way a foreign key is working. Foreign keys will only allow values in *parent* which already (meaning before the insert) exist in *fname*.

If this is not what you want, than please explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE fname(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname VARCHAR(29));

CREATE TABLE parent(
p_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id INT,
CONSTRAINT `fk11`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `fname` (`id`)
);
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

PS: Although SO is a community of people ready to help, it is always good to have a look at the docs or do a simple web search before asking a question here.